# In Alita: Battle Angel do cyborgs have stomachs?

Tags: movie, alita-battle-angel

Probably my favorite live action movie based on a manga, Alita: Battle Angel depicts a deep and detailed post apocalyptic world.

In some occasions we see Alita eating actual food and seemingly enjoy it.

So my question is:  Do cyborgs have the ability to make use of the energy they get from food and if so do they.. go to the toilet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you include the original source material of the manga, the answer is that yes, after the food is digested, it is excreted.

[image: A detailed view of a cyborg's body]

Although, at one point, Alita claims it's only to fuel her brain, presumably since the rest of her body uses the nuclear reactor.

[image: Alita eating chocolate and claiming that she needs the sugar for her brain]

There is also a non-canon omake strip, "[Creation of Alita's Innards](https://battleangel.fandom.com/wiki/Creation_of_Alita%27s_Innards)", which explores both a "glucose-only" option and the full experience. It does not make it clear which choice Ido made.

[image: Translated page in English]

Comment: Don't forget Alita: Holy Night in which Alita has a few problems with excretion

Comment: I don't have time to check it out fully, but https://mangarock.com/manga/mrs-serie-100334155 has those issues.

Comment: Cool!. I own the physical copies of Battle angel Alita deluxe edition but haven't read them yet.